# Doctrine 2 - How to use the Time column type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having a problem with Time column type : 
i have this part of my entity "Match" :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $creationDate;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="time",nullable=true)
 */
private $creationTime;
```

And every time i try to persist the entity i get the error :

Error: Call to a member function format() on string in TimeType.php

This is the part where i fill the CreationTime :

```
$time = date("H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));

$Match->setCreationTime($time);
```

I tried to check the TimeType.php file and i found out that this function is the source of the problem :

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getTimeFormatString()) : null;
}
```

to be more sure i checked the AbstractPlatform class and found out that the member method getTimeFormatString always returns this string : 'H:i:s'.

So any body can help ?

Comment: time... Maps and converts time data without date and timezone information. If you know that the data to be stored only needs to be a time without date, time and timezone information, you should consider using this type. Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP’s \DateTime object or null if no data is present..... see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html... then why are you working with date and strtotime functions you need to work with DateTime object

Comment: I see now, I needed to use the DateTime object instead, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

```
$Match->setCreationTime(new \Datetime());
```